# Solve $3^{x+1} = 2^x$

Tags: logarithms

So I have solved it two different ways, using $\log_2 $ of both sides: 
$x=x+1(\log_2 3)$ 
$x=x \log_2 3 + \log_2 3$ 
$ \log_2 3 = x(1- \log_2 3)$ 
$x= \frac {\log_2 3} {1-\log_2 3}$ 
$x= -2.71$ 
And $\log_3$ of both sides: 
$x+1=x(\log_3 2)$ 
$1=x(\log_3 2 -1)$ 
$x= \frac {1} {\log_3 2 -1}$ 
$x=-2.71$ 
However, is it also possible to use change of base law with the $\log_3$ version?
$x+1=\frac {\log_2 (2^x)} {\log_2 3}$
How would you simplify $\log_2 3 = \frac {x} {x+1}$ ?

Comment: Your solution is wrong, or, maybe that your equation is $3^{x+1}=2^x$?

Comment: If you mean $3^{x+1}=2^x$ edit your question by putting curly braces around the exponent: 3^{x+1}

Comment: @AbiH Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
$$3^{x+1}=2^x\iff \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x=3.$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We can simply use natural log to obtain

$$3^{x+1}= 2^x\iff (x+1)\log 3=x\log 2$$

then find $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$3^{x+1} = 2^x \implies \sqrt[x]{3^{x+1}} = 2 \implies 3^{\frac{x +1}{x}} = 2$$
$$\left(\frac{x +1}{x}\right) = \log_32$$
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) = \log_32$$
$$x = \frac{1}{\left(\log_32-1\right)}$$
$$x = -\frac{\ln \left(3\right)}{\ln \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$